# How can I refresh a tab from another using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to achieve something like Wordpress does when you create a new post. It allows you to preview your post by opening a new tab. If, after that, you edit the post and preview it again, rather than opening another tab, it refreshes the previously opened tab (provided it is still open).

From some research it seems I can open a new window and give it a name to identify it, like this:

`window.open(url,"foobar");`

But, how can I later refresh this tab? `location.reload()` does not seem to take a name as an argument.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I remember correctly this is the way to do it:

```
var win = window.open(url, "foobar");
win.location.reload();
```

Comment: In this case, I don't **have** to give it a name, since I'm assigning it to a variable anyways, right? I could just do `var win = window.open(url);`

Comment: @xbonez - But if you want to set its width and height and that kind of things, you'll have to. `window.open(url,"name","width=500,height=500");`

Comment: thanks. this helped me. just on more question, how do I switch to that tab? The page gets reloaded, but I want the focus also to be transferred to that tab

Comment: I thought `window.open()` opens up a popup.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the property window.opener.  See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

Comment: I think the OP wants to reload the new page which is opened. Not the window which opened it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by "storage" event. for more details follow

[Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230845/communication-between-tabs-or-windows)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage