# Jquery post to reload or refresh Another window

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Am developing a php mysql app with codeigniter for users on an intranet. It heavily uses jquery and flexigrid. One of the components on a page is a table which gets populated via jquery post based on user action/actions on other components of the same page ... So far, all works fine.

There are too many components (tables/forms, etc) on this page, and for lack of real estate, users have requested me to add functionality/ability to move one of the components to a new window. I can move the component in question to a new window, but am not sure how I could refresh that new window based on user activity on the default window - and thats where I could use some help.

An example of what I am looking for can be found in phpmyadmin, wherein you are able to edit a sql query in a popup window and on running the query, it updates another window with the results of the query - It also seems to know which window to update/refresh if there are multiple tabs/windows open ...

If you can give any hints on how to proceed with this, that'd would be very helpful ... thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I refresh a tab from another using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662107/how-can-i-refresh-a-tab-from-another-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Joao, that question indeed has given me pointers to what am looking for... though it did not come up in possible questions when I was posting this question. Will add a comment tomorrow after I experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

Look for window.opener in jquery you can use your querystring to pass data to the popup/form page

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to window.opener, Stefan - I didn't know about this. Will post feedback tomorrow after I experiment with it.