# refresh an already opened tab (not reload in a new window)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of tabs open, say Default.aspx and Default1.aspx, both the tabs are open, 
Now on the document ready of Default.aspx I need to refresh the existing Default1.aspx

I have tried many links, which opens a new window of the given URL (window.location.reload)

I want the existing tab to refresh, there is no need for it to get focus also.

Ps: I want this to have Cross-Browser-Compatibility as well, so any code with pure javascript would be very helpful.

Comment: If `Default.aspx` has opened `Default1.aspx` via javascript then it can refresh it via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662107/how-can-i-refresh-a-tab-from-another-using-javascript.  If not then I don't believe there is any way for a page to access other tabs that are currently open

Comment: unfortunately internet explorer is so old that you can't use [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) - as this is same domain, well crafted use of localStorage may help

Comment: @SteveGreatrex unfortunately the two pages are separate in nature and there is not parent child relationship amoing them

Comment: If the pages exist on the same server, I don't see why both pages couldn't be listening for a call serverside continuously, and then page 1 can send the call for page 2 to listen to and then refresh. I'm a front end developer though, and have never used the word 'server' so many times.